# How to push an ionic build to an ios device without opening xcode?

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am attempting to push an ionic project to an ios device that is connected to the computer.

I'm using this:

```
ionic cordova run ios --buildConfig=build-scripts/prod/ios-build.json --device --target=bb1538148abccba8dcff0ab15db8d232ed5117c2
```

The ipa file gets generated successfully. Then, ionic calls native-run, which hangs:

```
native-run ios --app "platforms/ios/build/device/Track Inspection.ipa" --target bb1538148abccba8dcff0ab15db8d232ed5117c2
```

If I run this same command using the --verbose flag I get this output:

```
client:usbmuxd connect: 6 on port 62078 +8ms
  protocol:usbmux socket write: {"messageType":"Connect","extraFields":{"DeviceID":6,"PortNumber":32498}} +5ms
  protocol:usbmux Response: {"MessageType":"Result","Number":0} +2ms
  client:lockdownd doHandshake +55ms
  client:lockdownd startSession: [object Object] +1ms
  protocol:lockdown socket write: {"Request":"StartSession","HostID":"<redacted>","SystemBUID":"<redacted>"} +15ms
  protocol:lockdown Response: {"EnableSessionSSL":true,"Request":"StartSession","SessionID":"<redacted>"} +5ms
  client:lockdownd Socket upgraded to TLS connection +20ms
  client:lockdownd startService: com.apple.mobile.mobile_image_mounter +1ms
  protocol:lockdown socket write: {"Request":"StartService","Service":"com.apple.mobile.mobile_image_mounter"} +16ms
  protocol:lockdown Response: {"EnableServiceSSL":true,"Port":52797,"Request":"StartService","Service":"com.apple.mobile.mobile_image_mounter"} +43ms
  client:usbmuxd connectUsbmuxdSocket +67ms
  client:usbmuxd connect: 6 on port 52797 +0ms
  protocol:usbmux socket write: {"messageType":"Connect","extraFields":{"DeviceID":6,"PortNumber":15822}} +65ms
  protocol:usbmux Response: {"MessageType":"Result","Number":0} +1ms
  client:mobile_image_mounter lookupImage +0ms
  protocol:lockdown socket write: {"Command":"LookupImage","ImageType":"Developer"} +2ms
```

it just hangs forever at this point. Not sure what to do.

If it helps, here is my env info:

```
Ionic CLI 5.2.8  
native-run 0.2.8  
cordova 9.0.0  
macOS Mojave 10.14.6  
XCode 10.3 Build Version 10G8
```

Answer (score 1):

you are doing everything right.

look at this known issues https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/4165 and https://github.com/ionic-team/native-run/issues/80 and follow the discussion